# display that precedes the number entered. (C programming)

Tags: c, integer

C Programming

Ask user to enter a random number between 1 and 100. Then ask how many numbers he wants to display that precedes first number he enters.

Let’s say if user enter 9 and wants 3 numbers that precedes 9, your program should display this:
• 6 7 8 9

Have no idea need some help.

Comment: Is there some sort of a question to be answered?

Comment: Could you answer this question?

Comment: You have to be more specific. Otherwise soon this question will be closed.

Comment: Have you started any code yet? Where are you stuck?

Comment: @Blastfurnace I don't know where to begin

Comment: [Do have a good C book to learn from?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: no i just look on the internet to learn it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For asking the user a question, you can use something like `printf` or `puts`.

To request numbers *from* the user, `scanf` is probably the best approach for the level you're working at.

By way of example, here's a complete program that asks the user for a number then gives them the next number:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {
    int num;
    printf ("Enter a number: ");
    if (scanf ("%d", &num) != 1) {
        puts ("That wasn't a valid number");
        return 1;
    }
    printf ("The next number is %d\n", num + 1);
    return 0;
}
```

Analysing that code, and what it does when it runs, should be enough to get you started.

For your specific project, the following pseudo-code should help:

```
print "Enter the ending number: "
input endnum
print "Enter the count of preceding numbers: "
input count

num = endnum - count
do:
    print num
    num = num + 1
while num <= endnum
```

That's the algorithm you can use, I won't provide it as C code since you'll become a better coder if you do that yourself. In any case, those pseudo-code lines all pretty much have a one-to-one mapping with C statements so it should be relatively easy to get something going.

Comment: But i need to ask  "how many numbers he wants to display that precedes first number he enters" in the program so i can not just do num+1.

Comment: @gtago4, I've given you *more* than enough to learn how to do it yourself. You're unlikely to become a decent developer if you get random people on the internet to do all your work for you :-) I'd suggest reading this answer then going and attempting it yourself. If you strike problems that you can't fix on your own, post your code in another question asking for help.