# Numbers precedes number user entered

Tags: c

> Ask user to enter a random number between 1 and 100. Then ask how many numbers s/he wants to display that precedes first number s/he enters.
>
> if user enter 9 and wants 3 numbers that precedes 9, your program should display this:
>
> ```
> 6 7 8 9
> ```

I can not finish it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main()
{
   int endnum, pre;


    printf("Enter a random number between 1 and 100: ");
    scanf("%d", &endnum);

    printf("how many numbers he wants to display that precedes first number you entered: ");
    scanf("%d", &pre);

    num = endnum - pre;
    printf (%d, num+1)
    num = num + 1
    while (num <= endnum)


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're pretty close.  You've got `pre` and `endnum`.  You just want to loop from `pre` to `endnum` (inclusive), and print out each of them.

You can use a `while` loop if you want to, but to me this situation lends itself more directly to a `for` loop.  Something like:

```
for (num = endnum - pre; num <= endnum; ++num)
{
    printf("%d ", num);
}
```

where `num` is pre-declared as a `int`.

Answer (score 1):

That's not a bad first attempt, you just need to fix one slight logic problem and some minor syntax things.

As per [my original pseudo-code from your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33115707/display-that-precedes-the-number-entered-c-programming/33115787#33115787), you need to have a loop doing the printing. You also need semicolons for statement terminators, quotes around strings, and to print the correct value. So change:

```
printf (%d, num+1)
num = num + 1
while (num <= endnum)
```

into:

```
do {
    printf ("%d ", num);
    num = num + 1;
} while (num <= endnum);
```

In addition, you'll also need to define `num` the same way you've defined `endnum` and `pre`.